# React-router4 display the name in component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I use react-router4 and try to display the name of the corresponding label in the commented location. I don't know how to solve this problem.
Does the react-router4 offer a solution to this problem? Can anyone show me how to do it?

Navigation.js:

```
        ...                        
<NavigationButton to="/" label="Dashboard" exact>
                                <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}
                                          selected={this.state.selected === "Dashboard"}
                                          onClick={() => {this.setState({selected: "Dashboard"})}}>
                                    <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
                                        <Home/>
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText classes={{primary: classes.primary}} inset primary="Dashboard"/>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </NavigationButton>
            <NavigationButton to="/payment" label="Payment" exact>
                        <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}
                                  selected={this.state.selected === "Payment"}
                                  onClick={() => {this.setState({selected: "Payment"})}}>
                            <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
                                <Payment/>
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText classes={{primary: classes.primary}} inset primary="Moje płatności"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </NavigationButton>

    ...
```

Header:

```
...
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className={classes.appFrame}>
                    <AppBar
                        className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
                            [classes.appBarShift]: open,
                            [classes[`appBarShift-left`]]: open,
                        })}
                    >
                        <Toolbar disableGutters={!open} className={classes.toolBar}>
                            <IconButton
                                color="inherit"
                                aria-label="Open drawer"
                                onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                                className={classNames(classes.menuButton, open)}
                            >
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
  {/* print "Dashboard" when I choose Dashboard, or print "Payment" when I choose payment in Navigation.js. */}
                            </Typography>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                    {before}
                    <main
                        className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-left`], {
                            [classes.contentShift]: open,
                            [classes[`contentShift-left`]]: open,
                        })}
                    >
                        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardComponent} />
                            <Route exact path="/payment" component={PaymentComponent} />
                            <Redirect to="/" />
                        </Switch>

                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

I use react-router4 and try to display the name of the corresponding label in the commented location. I don't know how to solve this problem.
Does the react-router4 offer a solution to this problem? Can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The approach is not right to display label of current component name with react-router as this will be an issue when it's a default export without even having a name. So it would be better to maintain a `const LABEL = { ... } // all label with pathname as keys`

So you can match `this.props.location.pathname` with your LABEL const object to display it properly.

```
const LABEL = { 
               dashboard : 'Dashboard',
               home: 'Home'
              }
```

in you render:

```
<Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
   {LABEL[this.props.location.pathname]}
</Typography>
```

I hope this would help, Ask any questions if it doesn't help

Comment: I do not understand. can I get more code from you for analysis?

Comment: @ReaxtX2 I have updated my answer that might have snytax errors. But you can still follow this approach. The example is added just to give you an idea, You could even place all const in your `Constants` file and later you can import `LABEL` from it. I hope this makes sense now

Comment: sure make it like const LABEL = { '/' : 'Dashboard' }. It works like a charm.